# Adding a filter to a Glassfish server

Tags: java, angularjs, cors, web.xml, servlet-filters

I have a Java application deployed under Glassfish 3.1.2.2 which uses `jersey` for serving rest services. The front end is written in `angularjs`. My `web.xml` is as follows:

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>qpark rest service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.restfulservice.restful;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>qpark rest service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/restservice/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>      
</web-app>
```

The front-end is running in another server (apache). When sending a request from the front-end Glassfish is responding with an error as follows:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin     'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

which is logic because front-end and back-end are served from different servers. In order to avoid  this I configured a `filter` which adds `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the response header. This filter has to be registered at the `web.xml` as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Gateway Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.filters.CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

My problem is that I want to map also this second filter to every restservice. That is, I want to add something like this

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Gateway Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/restservice/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But this is not allowed.

The question is how to add/combine/register these two filters in the `web.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is not a servlet but rather a servlet filter. Implement your servlet filter against the interface `javax.servlet.Filter`. Use the filter to process the request and/or response, add or remove information to the request / response and then pass it on to the next filter in the chain (if any).

```
package com.example.sample;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Sample implements Filter{

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Process the request / response here. Add or remove the information you need.
        // Add or edit the headers you want to
        chain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);            
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {


    }
}
```

To use the filter, you need to define and map it inside web.xml as follows:

```
<!--  List of filters -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>Authorization Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.sample.Sample</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Sample Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/foobar/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) are independently added w.r.t. servlets

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>ContainerResponseFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.filters.CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>...</param-name>
      <param-value>42</param-value>
   </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>ContainerResponseFilter</filter-name>
   <servlet-name>*</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
   ...
```